# Получить адрес файла с помощью ярлыка (.lnk) в JAVA

Tags: java

Есть ярлык на папку (.lnk), мне нужно, чтобы программа с помощью этого ярлыка получила адрес папки, на которую ярлык указывает. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Если хочется угореть по хардкору - вот [официальная спецификация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) формата LNK от Microsoft. Читаете, осознаёте, пишете прасер. Если же угорать не охота, то можно использовать [опыт наших зарубежных коллег](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309495/4863012), коллективный разум которых породил сразу несколько вариантов парсеров файлов LNK.

Answer (score 1):

Задачу получилось выполнить с помощью данного кода:
https://github.com/DmitriiShamrikov/mslinks